# How to fix "Mixed Content:" error when making API calls to elasticsearch from react

Tags: firebase, elasticsearch, axios, create-react-app, mixed-content

I am using the bitnami version of elasticsearch from firebase. I found out that it only connects to `http` and not `https` when i tried it using postman. My `create-react-app` is deployed to firebase and I am getting `Mixed Content:` error when I try to fetch data using the `axios` library.

Here id my code:

```
import axios from 'axios';

axios.get('http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx//elasticsearch/tasks/task/_search?default_operator=AND&q=*', {
    httpsAgent: agent,
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
        // 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Basic xxxxxxxxxx='
    }
});
```

and the error

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://xxx-xxxx.firebaseapp.com/tasks' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx//elasticsearch/tasks/task/_search?default_operator=AND&q=*'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
```